# property.GetValue(dynamictype,null) throw RuntimeBinderException

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a dynamic type object and I want to get all the values of every property from the object.

```
dynamic row = ....
```

I am using `property.GetValue(row, null)` throws a RuntimeBinderException.
How can I retrieve this value?

Comment: Could you please provide a more meaningful code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will iterate thru all *public properties*:

```
    dynamic something = new {id = "1", name = "name"};
    Type type = something.GetType();
    var properties = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var value = property.GetGetMethod().Invoke(something, null);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}", property.Name, value));
    }
```